# How to use the Nelder Meade Simplex algorithm in mathdotnet for function maximization

Tags: c#, numerical-analysis, math.net

In my C# program I have a dataset where each data point consists of:

- a stimulus intensity (intensity) as x-coordinate
- the percentage of correct response (percentageCorrect) to stimulus as y-coordinate

When the intensity is low percentageCorrect is low. When the intensity is high the percentageCorrect is high. The function graph is an S-shaped curve as the percentageCorrect reaches an asymptote at low and high ends.

I am trying to find the threshold intensity where percentageCorrect is half way between the asymtotes at either end (center of the S-shaped curve)

I understand this to be a function maximization problem that can be solved by the Nelder Meade Simplex algorithm.

I am trying to solve my problem using the [Nelder Meade Simplex algorithm in mathdotnet](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Optimization/NelderMeadSimplex.htm) and its [IObjectiveFunction](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Optimization/IObjectiveFunction.htm) parameter.

However, I am having trouble understanding the API of the NedlerMeadeSimplex class [FindMinimum method](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Optimization/NelderMeadSimplex.htm#FindMinimum) and the IObjectiveFunction [EvaluateAt](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Optimization/IObjectiveFunction.htm#EvaluateAt) method.

I am new to numerical analysis that is pre-requisite for this question.

Specific questions are:

- For the NedlerMeadeSimplex class [FindMinimum method](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Optimization/NelderMeadSimplex.htm#FindMinimum) what are the initialGuess and initialPertubation parameters?
- For the IObjectiveFunction [EvaluateAt](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Optimization/IObjectiveFunction.htm#EvaluateAt) method, what is the point parameter? I vaguely understand that the point parameter is a datum in the dataset being minimized
- How can I map my data set to this API and solve my problem?

Thanks for any guidance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial guess is a guess at the model parameters.

I've always used the forms that don't require an entry of the initialPertubation parameter, so I can't help you there.

The objective function is what your are trying to minimize. For example, for a least squares fit, it would calculate the sum of squared areas at the point given in the argument. Something like this:

```
private double SumSqError(Vector<double> v)
{
    double err = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        double y_val = v[0] + v[1] * Math.Exp(v[2] * x[i]);
        err += Math.Pow(y_val - y[i], 2);
    }
    return err;
}
```

You don't have to supply the point. The algorithm does that over and over while searching for the minimum. Note that the subroutine as access to the vector x.

Here is the code for a test program fitting a function to random data:

```
private void btnMinFit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random RanGen = new Random();
    x = new double[100];
    y = new double[100];

    // fit exponential expression with three parameters
    double a = 5.0;
    double b = 0.5;
    double c = 0.05;
    // create data set
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) x[i] = 10 + Convert.ToDouble(i) * 90.0 / 99.0; // values span 10 to 100
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        double y_val = a + b * Math.Exp(c * x[i]);
        y[i] = y_val + 0.1 * RanGen.NextDouble() * y_val;  // add error term scaled to y-value
    }

    // var fphv = new Func<double, double, double, double>((x, A, B) => A * x + B * x + A * B * x * x); extraneous test


    var f1 = new Func<Vector<double>, double>(x => LogEval(x));
    var obj = ObjectiveFunction.Value(f1);
    var solver = new NelderMeadSimplex(1e-5, maximumIterations: 10000);
    var initialGuess = new DenseVector(new[] { 3.0, 6.0, 0.6 });

    var result = solver.FindMinimum(obj, initialGuess);


    Console.WriteLine(result.MinimizingPoint.ToString());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have built a complete working Windows Forms implementation of the `NelderMeadSimplex.Minimum` function that can be found [here](https://github.com/davidjgall/NelderMeadSimplex). The code is somewhat self-documenting via embedded comments. Specific to your questions:

First: The `initialGuess` and `initialPerturbation` parameters work together to create an "initial simplex," wherein the `initialGuess` localizes the search for the minimum to a set of values of the variables or "location on the function" where you, the researcher, think the minimum might be nearby; and the `initialPerturbation` sets a conceptual "size" for the "initial simplex." The Math.NET implementation will set the `initialPerturbation` for you if you omit it, but for functions containing multiple local minima it might be advantageous to specify this parameter so as to confine the search to a localized region. For example, if the function is a 3D description of a bathtub where z = f(x) + g(y), the `initialGuess` [x, y] should be chosen such that the search is within the bounds of the perimeter of the bathtub and the algorithm will most likely find a suitable `initialPerturbation`; however, if the function describes a kitchen sink having two 'tubs' (local minima) conjoined by a ridge, failing to set a small enough `initialPerturbation` might result in the "wrong" local minimum being found instead of the desired local minimum.

Second: For the IObjectiveFunction EvaluateAt method, you need not involve yourself at that level of detail. Your task in implementing the `NelderMeadSimplex.Minimum` function is to write an equation function that takes in the parameters that control the equation of the curve over which you wish the `NelderMeadSimplex.Minimum` function to search in its quest for a set of values that fit your data. In other words, you have a preconceived idea of the form of the equation that "should" fit your data and you wish to find the parameters of that equation that best fit your data:

```
    private double TheEquation(double a, double b, double c, double x)
    {
        // The desired form of the equation of the curve to fit to the data
        // is chosen by the researcher and entered here. In this example we use
        // y = a + b * e^(c * x) where e is Euler's number.

        double y;
        y = a + b * Math.Exp(c * x);
        return y;
    }
```

The `NelderMeadSimplex.Minimum` function will then repetitively feed into this function values of the "point parameter" where the word "point" is used conceptually as a multi-dimensional construct consisting of the input parameters for the function you wrote above. In other words, the `NelderMeadSimplex.Minimum` function feeds your equation function trial values of its input parameters, then evaluates the function you wrote over and over, feeding in different trial values of the input parameters each time, until the output from your function settles down to "a minimum" (which will be explained below). The "point parameter" is just the list of input parameters to your function, the `a, b, and c` in my example:

`private double TheEquation(double a, double b, double c, double x)`

Note, specifically, that the input parameter list excludes the variable `x`
. Here, `x` is the domain variable over which your function will draw it's predictive curve and against which you'll need to test your research data. The equation is a continuous curve from which you need to extract point values at specific locations (in this case, values of `x`) for comparison with experimental data at those same values of `x`. In other words, the `NelderMeadSimplex.Minimum` function supplies the input *parameters* but not all of the input *variables* to your equation function and it's up to you to write a function to supply the remaining input variable(s). This new function is sometimes known as the "error function" which supplies the feedback into the `NelderMeadSimplex.Minimum` function so it can find it's way to a set of parameters that minimize the error between the predicted values from your equation and the actual research data values. To wit:

Third: You cannot just feed this `TheEquation` function to the `NelderMeadSimplex.Minimum` function and expect results, because you also need to somehow feed in your research data and compare the value given by the equation nearby to the individual research data points to see how closely the equation values match the values of the research data. The `NelderMeadSimplex.Minimum` function will then feed particular trial values of the parameters controlling the `TheEquation` function until it finds a set of parameter values that give a "best fit" of the equation to the research data. One common method of evaluating the "closeness" of the equation to the research data points is the method of least squares. By summing the "nearness" (deviation, or error) of each research data point from the value of the equation "near" that point, an *aggregate* error--a *single value*--can be accumulated that serves as a measure of the overall "goodness of fit" of your equation, using a particular set of parameters, to the research data.

So your task is to write a function that evaluates your equation at a series of points "near" to your research data points and aggregates the errors from testing your equation against each point in your research data set. The `NelderMeadSimplex.Minimum` function's job is to repetitively put in trial parameters to your equation in search of a minimization of this "goodness of fit" aggregate error value so as to yield a "best fit" set of parameters to your equation. So your equation function as written above needs to be *called* from within the error-reporting function which, in turn, is actually the function that your code supplies to the `NelderMeadSimplex.Minimum` function.

The following code implements the sum of squares with the presumption that the experimental research data consists of 100 data points whose (x, y) values are stored in the two global arrays `x[i]` and `y[i]`. The vector `v` is the "point parameter" discussed above which consists of three values for the trial parameter values of `a, b, and c` from the `TheEquation` function--these are the parameters whose values the `NelderMeadSimplex.Minimum` function will eventually report back to you when it finds values that minimize the output from this `SumOfSquaresOfErrors` function. Note that the `TheEquation` function is evaluated at the same `x[i]` values as the data points--this is just one way (of many ways) to define the "nearness" of the function to the data. In some applications, a more sophisticated method of establishing "nearness" may be required other than just the vertical offset of the data point from the function evaluated at the same ordinate. Also, be aware that there are libraries that implement these error functions much more robustly; I've simply written this one for illustrative purposes, but a working implementation should use one of the available library "norm" functions:

```
private double SumOfSquaresOfErrors(Vector<double> v)
{
    double err = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        double y_val = TheEquation(v[0], v[1], v[2], x[i]);
        err += Math.Pow(y_val - y[i], 2);
    }
    return err;
}
```

Finally, the implementation of the `NelderMeadSimplex.Minimum` function seems almost trivial after all the foregoing. First, declare that your error function (in this case, `SumOfSquaresOfErrors`) is the "value" of a new variable of type IObjectiveFunction; I like to think of this as nothing more than a pointer to the function, a way of telling the `NelderMeadSimplex.Minimum` function where it can find the *objective function* in order to call it, and from which to obtain the value of the error which `NelderMeadSimplex.Minimum` is charged with trying to minimize. This becomes the first argument to the `NelderMeadSimplex.Minimum` function. While it is possible to construct an object of type `NelderMeadSimplex` and work with that, I prefer the available static function invocation--the usage is the same.

Second, construct a vector that contains the `initialGuess` values of the (three, in this example) parameters that determine the specific shape of the curve given by your equation. In my `RunSolver` function below, these (three) parameters are passed in as the vector called `Coefficients` and are generated elsewhere (or hard-coded as in this example). This is the second parameter to the `NelderMeadSimplex.Minimum` function. If an `initialPertubation` is used, it would become the third parameter. I leave construction of such a vector to you, but it should have the same number of elements as the `initialGuess` vector since it is merely a declaration of how much (or how little) the `NelderMeadSimplex.Minimum` function should offset the next set of guess values from the `initialGuess` values on subsequent invocations of the error function.

The remaining two parameters to the `NelderMeadSimplex.Minimum` function are self-explanatory.

The output from the `NelderMeadSimplex.Minimum` function is of type `MinimizationResult` and should be captured into a variable of that type from which the outputs are properties that can be extracted in the usual way. The fitted parameters for your equation--the results for which you undertook all this--are stored in the vector called `MinimizationResult.MinimizingPoint` and the final or "minimized" "goodness of fit" value returned from your error function (`SumOfSquaresOfErrors`) is stored as the `MinimizationResult.FunctionInfoAtMinimum.Value`. Extract these properties from your `MinimizationResult` variable and use or display them as needed. In the example code, I store these results in individual global variables for use elsewhere, as well as using them to construct a data set of `y_out[i]` values for graphic display of the fitted curve (as a series of connected line segments) on the same field on which the research data points are plotted.

```
private void RunSolver(Vector<double> Coefficients)
{
    //NelderMeadSimplex implementation begins here
    IObjectiveFunction objFunc = ObjectiveFunction.Value(SumOfSquaresOfErrors);
    MinimizationResult minResult = NelderMeadSimplex.Minimum(objectiveFunction: objFunc, initialGuess: Coefficients, convergenceTolerance: 1e-5, maximumIterations: 10000);
    //NelderMeadSimplex implementation ends here

    // Outputs
    FitCfs = minResult.MinimizingPoint;    // Fitted Coefficients
    ErrorValue = minResult.FunctionInfoAtMinimum.Value;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) y_out[i] = TheEquation(FitCfs[0], FitCfs[1], FitCfs[2], x[i]);

    DisplayResults(minResult.MinimizingPoint.ToString());
    graphicsForm.UpdateData(x, y, y_out, minResult, a, b, c);
}
```

Feel free to download, use, fork, and/or modify the linked code for your own purposes without restriction.